# Max of column sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table like this:

Table: Albums

```
ID  NAME  USER_ID
---
1   Selfie 1
2   Me and VIPs 1
3   Me  2
4   My pictures 5
5   images  7
6   My POTUS Images 8
7   My Selfies  10
```

the output should be something like

MaxAlbumAUserHas: 2

Because the user with id 1 has 2 albums

I want to get the user who has most albums, how can I query this?

Thanx in advance

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by user, sort the results by the number of albums descending and return the top row:

```
select 'MaxAlbumAUserHas: ' || count(*) result
from Albums
group by user_id
order by count(*) desc limit 1;
```

or with `count()` window function without the need of `group by`:

```
select 'MaxAlbumAUserHas: ' || count() over (partition by user_id) result
from Albums
order by count() over (partition by user_id) desc limit 1;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hKpHJZrzEASDe9K6xiSmNk/2).
Results:

```
| result              |
| ------------------- |
| MaxAlbumAUserHas: 2 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `group by` to count the albums.  Then order and limit to the number of rows that you want:

```
select userid
from t
group by userid
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Seems like OP wants the maximum _number of albums_, not the userid.

Comment: Yes, I want to get the user id of the user who has the max number of albums